# symfony - doctrine admin generator filters and relations

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have an admin module, that lists orders.

One of the filters is a drop down, which lists the order_status and is a relation to the order_status table.

These order_id's are an id, from 1-10.

What I'm looking to do, is to filter by more than one of these order_id's.

So something like `1,2,3,4,5` or `6,7,8,9,10`

Is this possible, or do I need to create a custom filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Allow to your order widget multiple selections.

Set option `'multiple' => true`

**Update:**
Try to handle value of orders types manually. Here is example:

```
  public function addOwnGroupIdColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value)
  {
    if (!$value)
    {
      return;
    }

    $query->leftJoin($query->getRootAlias().'.OwnGroups pgr');

    $query->andWhereIn("pgr.id", $value);
  }
```

Locate this method into your filter class.

Comment: Ok, I added the following: `$this->widgetSchema['status_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
      'model' => 'order_status',
      'multiple' => true
    ));` which gave me: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. any ideas?

Comment: Try to use sfWidgetFormChoice instead of sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice